# How to deal with multiple serial ports for R/W using twisted?

Tags: python, serial-port, twisted

Going through the twisted finger tutorial and seen the SO questions:

- [Question-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17739955/twisted-python-script-on-raspberry-pi-debian-to-communicate-with-arduino-via-u)
- [Question-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18116670/twisted-python-pausing-a-serial-port-read)

However, I can't (yet) write a twisted program that can read & write from multiple serial ports, especially where the protocol involves reading single or multiple lines, and writing back to the device accordingly.

What I am trying to do is open 2 pairs (i.e. total of 4) serial ports, for 2 modems. Communication with modems is using Hayes AT command set. While most of the command/response exchanges with modem is via the command-port, there are few diagnostic information that are available only via the diagnostic-port, for each modem. The diagnostic information should lead to a state-machine (device-state, connection-state) to be modified.

Here is a rough skeletal program of what I understand as the potential approach (based on single port examples):

```
class CommandProtocol(LineOnlyReceiver):
    def connectionMade(self):
        log.msg("Connected to command port")

    def lineReceived(self, line):
        print repr(line)
        processCommandLine(line)

class DiagnosticProtocol(LineOnlyReceiver):
    def connectionMade(self):
        log.msg("Connected to diag port")

    def lineReceived(self, line):
        print repr(line)
        processDiagnosticLine(line)

...

# modem1 ports
cmdPort[0] = SerialPort(CommandProtocol, "/dev/ttyUSB0", reactor, 115200)
diagPort[0] = SerialPort(DiagnosticProtocol, "/dev/ttyUSB1", reactor, 115200)
# modem2 ports
cmdPort[1] = SerialPort(CommandProtocol, "/dev/ttyUSB3", reactor, 115200)
diagPort[1] = SerialPort(DiagnosticProtocol, "/dev/ttyUSB4", reactor, 115200)
```

However, I am at loss, as to how do I do the following:

- How/where do I accept CLI input from user, that then triggers sending a set of AT command to the modems ?
- Correlate the information received on command port for ttyUSB0 & ttyUSB1 for modem1, and similarly for the other pair for modem2 ? Note that each modem has it's own state-machine (device-state and connection-state)
- Does twisted provide any mechanism for management of multiple state-machines by application ?
- It is possible that the USB-serial connection to the modem is destroyed due to the modem being unplugged, and re-established on being plugged back-in. How can I detect such events and add the monitoring of the corresponding device-ports to the reactor ? Currently, I'm doing it statically in the main application.

Comment: Does it have to be [Twisted](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/)?

Comment: Not really, it doesn't. If there were a simpler solution, I'd prefer to start with it. Performance might be one concern, but not an immediate one. The async event-model is what attracted me to Twisted, but I've to admit that it's been a bit of a struggle (especially for someone in a hurry).

Comment: I'd like to suggest that you have a look at using [circuits](https://github.com/circuits/circuits) for this as it **is** event-driven with a much better rachitecture and set of API(s) to deal with this kind of "concurrency" and "coordination" without getting lost in "callbacks".

Comment: This is precisely the type of project that twisted excels at. It is a framework that has a steep leaning curve, but when mastered it provides nearly optimal speed and flexibility for multifaceted IO in python.  The best tutorial I've found for it is the krondo Twisted Introduction http://krondo.com/?page_id=1327

Comment: @JamesMills, firstly thanks for pointing me to circuits. Before narrowing down on twisted, I'd done what I thought was a rather thorough study (mostly theoretical though, i.e. without writing any code), and "circuits" hadn't popped on my radar even once. I've gone through it's beginner tutorial, and I've to admit that it is extremely easy to follow. I found that there is a serial communication component, and an example, though the notice that it is untested, is a bit worrying. Does circuits have an active community and user base ?

Comment: @MikeLutz, thanks for the pointer to the krondo.com tutorial. I've started going through it earlier, however I was looking at something that could allow me to progress faster. Doesn't look like that there's any simpler way.

Comment: @icarus74: krondo is the best, but your certainly right that its not fastest (though even if your sprinting I would recommend continuing to read that at nights until you've made it all the way through).  As I've worked in Twisted the fastest resources have been all the examples on http://twistedmatrix.com and here on SO.  The twistedmatrix examples can get you almost anywhere, but you have to keep an eye on which Twisted version your looking (the examples are different by versions).  When you can't connect the dots with twistedmatrix, thats when you fold over to krondo (or add Qs here on SO)

Comment: @icarus74 "active" is hard to measure :) But yes we do have an active community and developers working on circuits all the time in the "spare time" we have :)

Comment: @JamesMills, realized that you are the lead developer of circuits. Do you think that the serial port functionality of circuits is reasonably well tested and stable ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Note on your example code

I don't see you instantiating your classes before registering them to the reactor.  I expect that will fail badly.  Here is a similar snippet of running code of mine:

```
# stuff to process messages coming from the serial port
class SerialEater(basic.LineReceiver):
    statusCallback = None

    def __init__(self):
        self.keyinprocess = None

    def lineReceived(self, data):
      self.dealWithSerial(data)

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
      if(reactor.running):
        print "Serial lost but reactor still running! reason: " + str(reason) + " at time " + time.asctime()
    [...etc...]



# Register the serialport into twisted
serialhandler = SerialEater()                   # <------------- instantiate
SerialPort(serialhandler, '/dev/ttyUSB0', reactor, baudrate=115200)
```

---

> How/where do I accept CLI input from user, that then triggers sending a set of AT command to the modems ?

Much like how you can register Serial handlers into Twisted, you can register handlers for standard io, for instance:

```
# stuff to pull cbreak char input from stdin
class KeyEater(basic.LineReceiver):

    def __init__(self):
      self.setRawMode() # Switch from line mode to "however much I got" mode

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
      if(reactor.running):
        self.sendLine( "Keyboard lost but reactor still running! reason: " + str(reason) + " at time " + time.asctime())

    def rawDataReceived(self, data):
      key = str(data).lower()[0]
      try:
        if key == '?':
          key = "help"
     [...etc...]

# register the stdio handler into twisted
keyboardobj = KeyEater()
keyboardobj.serialobj = serialhandler
stdio.StandardIO(keyboardobj,sys.stdin.fileno())
```

---

> Correlate the information received on command port for ttyUSB0 & ttyUSB1 for modem1, and similarly for the other pair for modem2 ? Note that each modem has it's own state-machine (device-state and connection-state)

In normal use, each connection-instance is going to have its own state machine (wrapped up in the instance of the class that you register into the reactor along with the connection).

You as the programmer choose how you want to connect the states of the classes, but often its via pushing reference to the partner classes.

Below, this answer contains runnable code that will illustrate how data is connected between state-machines/interface.  This is also illustrated in this SO: [Persistent connection in twisted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23265609/persistent-connection-in-twisted/23274411#23274411)

---

> Does twisted provide any mechanism for management of multiple state-machines by application ?

If by "application" you mean "your twisted code" then then the answer is absolutely YES!

The typical Twisted app is an array of state-machines, all with some amazingly well defined interfaces.  I started my Twisted adventure intending to write an app with two state-machines (a serial and keyboard), but when I became comfortable with twisted was doing I realized it was trivial to add on extra interfaces and state-machines (through all the wonder of the tx libraries).  All in one afternoon I added on a rough web interface, a websocket interface, then laid SSL over both and even added on an SSH debug interface.  Once you get a rolling, adding interfaces and state-machines become trivial.

In many (all?) cases, the twisted model is that a state-machine will reside in an instantiated class that is tied to a connection and that has been registered into the (one-and-only-one) main event-loop.

With connection types that spawn off new state-machines (think http connections) you  register one factory-class/state-machine along with the listening connection which together enable the app of spawning off new classes/state-machines for each new connection.  Twisted applications routinely 10s or even 100s of thousands of concurrent instances of state when run at scale.

Twisted is amazing if your trying to glue together different protocols and states (... with all of it being in a event loop of your choice (select/epoll/kqueue/etc))

The following is runnable sample code that should illustrate many of these points.  Read the comments before `def main()` for more background on the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#
# Frankenstein-esk amalgam of example code
#   Key of which comes from the Twisted "Chat" example
#   (such as: http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/12.0.0/core/examples/chatserver.py)

import sys # so I can get at stdin
import os # for isatty
import termios, tty # access to posix IO settings
from random import random
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.internet import stdio # the stdio equiv of listenXXX
from twisted.protocols import basic # for lineReceiver for keyboard
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol, ServerFactory

class MyClientConnections(basic.LineReceiver):

    def __init__(self):
        self.storedState = "Idle"
        self.connectionpos = None

    def connectionMade(self):
        self.factory.clients.append(self) # <--- magic here :
            # protocol automagically has a link to its factory class, and
            # in this case that is being used to push each new connection
            # (which is in the form of this class) into a list that the
            # factory can then access to get at each of the connections
        self.connectionpos = str(self.factory.clients.index(self)) # figure out 
                                      # where I am in the connection array
        print "Got new client! (index:", self.connectionpos + ")"
        self.transport.write("---\nYour connection: " + self.connectionpos + "\n---\n")

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        print "Lost a client!"
        self.factory.clients.remove(self)

    # used to pretend that something was typed on a telnet connection
    def fakeInput(self, message):
        self.transport.write("FAKING Input: '" + message + "'\n")
        self.lineReceived(message)

    #this is only in a def on its own so I can lump my demo callLater
    def stateUpdate(self, newState, delay):
        self.storedState = newState
        # the following is a hack to fake data coming in this interface
        reactor.callLater(delay, self.fakeInput, newState + " DONE")

    def processInput(self, newState):
        # all the logic in here is junk to make a demo, real code may or may-not look like
        # this.  This junk logic is an example statemachine though
        if self.storedState == "Idle":
            if newState == "start":
                self.stateUpdate("State A", 1)        
                # send a message to this connection
                self.transport.write("starting state machine\n")
                # send a message to the term in which the script it running
                print "Connection [" + self.connectionpos + "] starting state machine"
        elif self.storedState == "State A":
            if newState == "State A DONE":
                self.transport.write("Beginning state B\n")
                self.stateUpdate("State B", 2)
        elif self.storedState == "State B":
            if newState == "State B DONE":
                self.transport.write("Beginning state C\n")
                self.stateUpdate("State C", 2)
        elif self.storedState == "State C":
            if newState == "State C DONE":
                self.storedState = "Idle"
                # send a message to this connection
                self.transport.write("Returning to Idle state\n")
                # send a message to the term in which the script it running
                print "Connection [" + self.connectionpos + "] return to Idle state"

    def lineReceived(self, line):
        # print "received '" + line +"' from connection", self.factory.clients.index(self)
        self.processInput(line)

class MyServerFactory(ServerFactory):
    protocol = MyClientConnections

    def __init__(self):
        self.clients = [] # this gets filled from the class above

    def sendToAll(self, message):
      for c in self.clients:  # Read MyClientConnections class for background
        c.transport.write(message)

    def randStart(self, width):
      for c in self.clients:
        startDelay = random() * width
        print "Starting client " + str(c.connectionpos) + " in " +str(startDelay) + " secs" 
        reactor.callLater(startDelay, c.processInput, "start")

# to set keyboard into cbreak mode -- just because I like it that way...
class Cbreaktty(object):
    org_termio = None
    my_termio = None

    def __init__(self, ttyfd):
        if(os.isatty(ttyfd)):
            self.org_termio = (ttyfd, termios.tcgetattr(ttyfd))
            tty.setcbreak(ttyfd)
            print '  Set cbreak mode'
            self.my_termio = (ttyfd, termios.tcgetattr(ttyfd))
        else:
          raise IOError #Not something I can set cbreak on!

    def retToOrgState(self):
        (tty, org) = self.org_termio
        print '  Restoring terminal settings'
        termios.tcsetattr(tty, termios.TCSANOW, org)


class KeyEater(basic.LineReceiver):

    def __init__(self, factoryObj):
        self.setRawMode() # Switch from line mode to "however much I got" mode
        # the following is one of the key connecting ideas in twisted, the object
        # that contains another state machine (really all of the tcp statemachines)
        # has been passed into this class via its init.
        self.factoryObj = factoryObj

    def rawDataReceived(self, data):
        key = str(data).lower()[0]
        if key == 's':
            # The following line is going to call (from within the factory object)
            # the random start def
            self.factoryObj.randStart(5)
        elif key == 'd':
            print "State Dump of connections"
            print "-------------------------"
            for c in self.factoryObj.clients:
                print "#" + str(c.connectionpos) + "      " + c.storedState
        elif key == 'q':
            reactor.stop()
        else:
            print "--------------"
            print "  If you haven't already, connect to this script via a"
            print "  'telnet localhost 5000' at least one (multiple connections"
            print "  are better)"
            print "Press:"
            print "      s  - randomly start all clients"
            print "      d  - dump the state of all connected clients"
            print "      q  - to cleanly shutdown"
            print " Note: you can type commands in the connections, things"
            print "       most useful of which is 'start'"
            print "---------------"

# Custom tailored example for SO:30397425
# 
# This code is a mishmash of styles and techniques. Both to provide different examples of how
# something can be done and because I'm lazy.  Its been built and tested on OSX and linux,
# it should be portable (other then perhaps termal cbreak mode).  If you want to ask
# questions about this code contact me directly via mail to mike at partialmesh.com
#
# While it isn't directly using serial ports, the tcp connections that its using are a good
# parallel.
#
# It should be used by running the script and then opening up many windows telnet'ing into
# localhost 5000.
#
# Once running press any key in the window where the script was run and it will give
# instructions.  
# The normal use case would be to type "s" to queue statemachine
# start-ups, then repeatedly press 'd' to dump the status of all the state machines
#
# 'start' can be typed into any of the telnet connections to start them by hand too.


def main():
    client_connection_factory = MyServerFactory()

    try:
      termstate = Cbreaktty(sys.stdin.fileno())
    except IOError:
      sys.stderr.write("Error: " + sys.argv[0] + " only for use on interactive ttys\n")
      sys.exit(1)

    keyboardobj = KeyEater(client_connection_factory)

    stdio.StandardIO(keyboardobj,sys.stdin.fileno())
    reactor.listenTCP(5000, client_connection_factory)
    reactor.run()
    termstate.retToOrgState()
if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

---

> It is possible that the USB-serial connection to the modem is destroyed due to the modem being unplugged, and re-established on being plugged back-in. How can I detect such events and add the monitoring of the corresponding device-ports to the reactor ? Currently, I'm doing it statically in the main application.

After research I don't have an easy answer.  I still suspect that the following logic will be close to a solution but I didn't have any luck finding code that implements this today.

My guess is there will be a reasonable way to figure out if a USB event has occurred, and work out if a serial device has been added.  But I doubt there will a good way to figure out if it is one of your serial devices - much less if its your Command or Diagnostic interface (Unless your building hardware and can control the USB IDs of the devices)

Events are fired on errors with serial ports (at least from my experience on linux), but I'm unsure how/where a USB unplug would register.

---

#### Other links that might be of use to you

- Twisted implementation of `Utilities for talking to a GSM modem over
  USB via AT commands`:  https://github.com/smn/txgsm
- Twisted implementation of weather station through USB:
  https://gist.github.com/claws/2464017

Comment: Thanks a lot Mike, for a rather comprehensive answer, and sharing your rather encouraging learning experience. Have understood that for every connection instance there is an interface specific state, however, I think I need to make some significant progress with Twisted before I'd be able to fully comprehend and appreciate how state correlation between 2 connections (on different interfaces) can be established.

Comment: @icarus74 Thanks!  My goal is to do (at least) one more refresh on this answer, when I do I'll try and factor in an example of how I would communicate between state-machines, between the keyboard state-machine and the serial-machine (which would be applicable between two serial machines)

Comment: Excellent. Shall look forward to it.

Comment: @icarus74 I've added an extensive block of (runnable) sample code that should illustrate any other points that were fuzzy.  Be sure to read the block of comments above `def main()` and run the code to better understand what it is up to.  All-in-all I think this represents a fairly complete answer to your question, so if you agree I would appreciate it if you marked this as the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Mike. I've been going through the Twisted tutorials and slowly making progress. The explanation and code in this answer would be additionally quite useful. Thanks also for the pointer to txgsm project and the USB weather-station one.

Comment: I think I've found something that should help with the USB serial device plug/unplug event identification and subsequent state-machine updates. Here are two relevant links (one [uses pyudev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469243/how-can-i-listen-for-usb-device-inserted-events-in-linux-in-python) and the other [uses udev-notify](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116536/usb-connect-disconnect-notification)).

Comment: @icarus74 that looks like great stuff!  I'll have to investigate if it will help me (at first glance it looks like it will, thanks for pointing that out!). When looking at other libraries remember you must twist-ize them or they can freeze the twisted reactor.  Searching for 'pyudev' and twisted yeilded http://pastebin.com/TnrsS15s which may do the trick

Comment: Indeed... landed on the same pastebin.